# Android doesn't send button events from Bluetooth Headset

Tags: android, events, bluetooth, headset

I've been working on sending sound/music to Bluetooth headset. 
I've implemented MEDIA_BUTTON receiver and it didn't work. After some debugging I've noticed the receiver works fine because it receives button press from headphones but not from bluetooth headset. 
To be 100% sure I've tested this headset on default mediaplayer and it also didn't respond to any button click except volume up/down.
I've tested it with two bluetooth headsets from different producers.

Am I doing something wrong or does some of bluetooth headsets just simply not send those intents?

I've already tested audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver( );
Device: SGS2
Android: 4.1.2

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where is the code that you think contains the problem?